# "I am a legend" vs. "I am legend"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, determiners, zero-article

Which sentence makes sense, the first or the second?

> 1. I am      legend.
> 2. I am  **a**  legend.

Comment: Are you thinking of the film [I am Legend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Legend_(film)) and/or 1954 novel  and asking yourself why it was called that? Both sentences make sense according to context. If I am talking about the movie it's 1); if I am boasting about myself it's 2).

Comment: This is just an ELL question. The simple answer is it is normally "I am a legend."  The other version is (let's put it this way) poetic or dramatic; basically "it's wrong" if you said that normally, in speech.

Comment: @JoeBlow I was inclined to think ELL too, but "I am legend" is actually correct and means something distinct from "I am a legend". It's just not something you'd hear every day, like you wouldn't hear "I committed genocide" every day. Dramatic, yes, wrong, no. (Well, genocide would be wrong.)

Comment: TBC, it's wrong in the sense that: **it is not what he meant**. Quite simply, he's trying to say "I am a legend", not "I am legend" (you have explained nicely what the latter means).

Answer (score 6):

Either works, but they have different meanings, and *I am a legend* is probably the one you want.

*[Legend](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/legend?s=t)* (Dictionary.com) means:

> **1.** a nonhistorical or unverifiable story handed down by tradition from earlier times and popularly accepted as historical.
>
> **6.** a collection of stories about an admirable person.
>
> **7.** a person who is the center of such stories
> *"She became a legend in her own lifetime."*

*I am a legend* would use definition 7 above, meaning that I am an amazing person.

*I am legend* would use definition 1 or 6 above, and would mean that I embody unverifiable history or myth, that my whole existence is shrouded in fable. This isn't a normal thing to say. While this concept is too stilted or dramatic for usual speech, there is a 1954 novel and a 2007 movie called *[I Am Legend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Legend_(novel))*, along these very lines.

It's confusing whether you meant to ask about *a* vs. *an*, since the question doesn't include this debate, but you should never say *I am **an** legend*, as *a* is always used before a consonantal sound.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase

> I am legend

is a case of the use of *legend* as a collective noun.

For example of such cases

- Legend has it that your orgasm lasts an hour.
- You are legend, in office-talk about your record.
- She is orgasm, because she makes every man in the office get an instant boner.
- She is honey, delectable and sweet.
- I am furniture to my boss. He uses the electronic roster to tell me what to do, without telling me what to do.
- Soil is essential to the growth of plants - well irrigated, aerated and nutrient-absorbent soil.
- I am Revolution, Evolution, Convolution and Truth. No one comes to the gods but by me.

Sorry for the pornographic phrases, with which many might be familiar, to tickle your mind.

Comment: Good Lord! Someone rate this answer "X".

Comment: I am 'sexually frustrated'